# Can we package Layout assignment for Record Types and Record Type page assignment via PS?

Tags: managed-package, 2gp

Is there any place we can refer, which metadata can be added to a 2G managed package.

For example, I need to know whether we can package the following option in a 2G managed package,

Layout assignment for Record Types via PS/ Layout Assignment.
Lightning record page assignment to record page and profile via PS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/50) is the best source for which components are packageable in 1GP ("Classic Packaging") and 2GP ("Managed Packaging").

What you're referring to are not metadata components, though, but elements of components. The references for specific component behaviors are the [ISVforce Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm) and the [Metadata API Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm).

> Layout assignment for Record Types via PS/ Layout Assignment. Lightning record page assignment to record page and profile via PS.

Those attributes are part of Profiles, not Permission Sets.

Comment: David, Many Thanks. This is what I am looking forward.